# Python 2 and 3 compatible way to call intern()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, string-interning

How do I write code that uses Python's `intern` that will work (be compatible) with both Python 2 and Python 3?  Is there a clean way to do it?

In Python 2, intern is a builtin, so you use `intern()`.  In Python 3, it has been moved to the `sys` module, so you're supposed to use `sys.intern()`.  It seems that `intern()` works on Python 2 but not Python 3, and `sys.intern()` works on Python 3 but not Python 2.  Is there any clean syntax that will work on both Python 2 and Python 3, without using version detection (ugly)?

Comment: I should point out that `intern()` is a serious micro-optimization, that the interpreter will likely do it automatically in all the obvious cases, and that in the vast majority of cases, the gains from interning your strings are simply not significant enough to justify the added code complexity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
try:
    from sys import intern
except ImportError:
    pass
```

This should work on both.

With `six` package:

```
from six.moves import intern
```

Answer (score 3):

Same as always.

```
try:
  intern
except NameError:
  from sys import intern
```